# Get Response Back from ASPX page in Android

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, vb.net

I have an Android application that makes a call to an ASPX page on a server, which does some database work and return fine (most of the time). However, I would like to have some verification that process executed fine. Hence I put the following line in my ASPX code after which the Sub Ends.

```
Response.AddHeader(CONFIG.REG_RESPONSE, CONFIG.REG_ADDED)
```

**And these lines in my Android**

```
OutputStream out = httpCon.getOutputStream();
out.write(bytes);
out.close();
int status = httpCon.getResponseCode();
strReceivedURL = httpCon.getURL().getFile();
strReturnedResponse = httpCon.getHeaderField(Config.REG_RESPONSE);    
Log.d(DEBUG, "Response Header:" + strReturnedResponse);
```

However, it returns null. Also, sorry for this stupid question, but if I put

```
Response.Redirect("/") 'Redirecting to home page
```

would it case Response.Header(s) to be null? What is the best way to handle requests like these? I am using an ASPX page (just like a Servlet), and this aspx page has no HTML in it.

Comment: A little more details will be highly appreciated.

Comment: @vjdhama: Sorry for the confusion. Please see updated code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to place that line at the top of your page

```
Response.AddHeader(CONFIG.REG_RESPONSE, CONFIG.REG_ADDED)
```

oh and do **not** redirect, this will cause unexpected behavior

Comment: I believe you are right, if I am not redirecting then I am getting the Response.Header back from my ASPX page. I am putting different values for CONFIG.REG_RESPONSE based on different conditions.

Comment: @programmerboy cool if you ever need my help again , leave a comment here